# chrome.runtime.onStartup never fires?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Consider the following Chrome extension:

### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Test onStartup",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

### eventPage.js

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() { 
    console.log("I started up!");
    chrome.storage.local.set({"startedUp": true});
});
```

[`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onStartup) is documented as firing "when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up", and I would've suspected that it also fires upon reloading the extension. However, upon restarting the browser or reloading the extension, I do not see the `console.log` message in the `_generated_background_page.html`'s console, and 
`chrome.storage.local.get("startedUp", function(v) { console.log(v) })` yields no results, so I suspect that the listener was not called.

Am I misunderstanding when this event is triggered or binding to it incorrectly or anything like that? Is it an issue with Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on Linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you close chrome its background process keep on running. Make sure to kill all the process named as `chrome` or similar before starting chrome again.

Comment: this doesn't fix it in my case, I just can't get the onStartup event to fire at all

Comment: Same experience as @Marnes. I wonder if it has to do with unpacked extensions?

Comment: To get the changes made to the background service worker to show up (like adding this listener), I ended up having to remove and re-add my unpacked extension.

This is in contrast to changes made to the default popup, which show up any time the extension is closed and reopened.

Answer (score 14):

`chrome.runtime.onStartup` is only called when Chrome starts, not when the extension starts.

`chrome.runtime.onInstalled` is called when you manually reload the extension within chrome://extensions, or when the extension calls `chrome.runtime.reload()`.

Comment: Mkay, sounds like my guess was wrong. I'm still not sure why I'm not seeing it fire when Chrome starts either, though…

Comment: is there an event when extension starts?

Answer (score 5):

Heads-up about this event which - in hindsight - is kinda obvious: your eventListener won't be fired if you register it after any async callbacks. You have to register it during the initial loading, outside of any callbacks.

In my case it wasn't getting fired because I was registering it as part of my "main" method, which was called after a settings validation, which requires a callback.

Comment: For me, disabling all my scripts on my `popup` page made the background script's event work. Not sure why.

Comment: Commenting from the future:  Top Level Await will break onStartup and onInstall.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.runtime.on*` events must be defined outside of any functions or closures.

Watch out for Webpack/TypeScript/Babel/GCJ and other transpilers.

Webpack by default wraps your code in an immediately invoked function expression `(() => { /* code */ })()`. You can [turn it off](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputiife) by adding to your `webpack.config.js`:

```json
  output: {
    iife: true,
  },
```

Finally, in Manifest V3, you should register these in your background service workers.