# Google Chrome extension (Fire a event when extension starts)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to fire a event just when my chrome extension starts. How do I achieve this? Is there a event listener that triggers when extension starts?

for example:-

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
        console.log('i will run once!');
});
```

Similar to this but not on installed but on start and it should only fire once during the extension's run time which is when it starts.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an onload event in your [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and put the code that you want to be executed on extension "start-up" in there.

Example (inside `background.js`):

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Extension has started...");
};
```

That message will be logged (once) when:

- Extension is installed
- Chrome is started (and extension is enabled)
- Extension is enabled from disabled state

Comment: its not working for me D: so i added "background":{"scripts":["background.js"]} in my manifest and i created background.js and added ur window.onload function there. but I never get the console.log().

Comment: Where are you looking for the console message? It will happen on the background page which you can inspect using the chrome://extensions page

Comment: I right clicked on the default_popup page and did inspect element. Is that not where it should console.log() ?

Comment: There is a link on the chrome://extensions page to "Inspect views". See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10082021/845680

Comment: Oh i see now where it outputs the console.log(). This is not what i wanted though D: What it should do is once i launch the extension's default pop_up, it should run the function once. After user closes the extension's default pop_up and opens again, the function should run again once and so on.

Comment: That is quite different from the extension startup! I would call that the "popup startup". However, you can reuse the above idea and move it over to the popup file. Just move the code to your popup file (inside `<script></script>` tags, or better yet a separate JS file) and it will execute each time the popup is opened.

Comment: Whether it is `window.onload` or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`, it is only a DOM event and only works when the background page is opened.
But it can indeed replace the `chrome.runtime.onStartup` startup event, because the browser will trigger the load event when it starts.
But more suggestion is to use `onStartup` because it is more reliable.

Comment: If the code inside background.js : ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "onStartup" event?

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function callback)

[See Google documentation here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup)

Comment: unfortunately that's not what i am looking for D: . I already tried this and it did not work and I found this answer on why it did not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621545/chrome-runtime-onstartup-never-fires . I want a event when extension starts not when chrome starts. Thanx for your help thought :D .

Answer (score 0):

Just place any code to `background.js` and it will execute when extension starts

```
console.log("extension starts");
```