# Is there a way to get a chrome extension to automatically run on chrome start up?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension, designed to collect the email address of the user signed into the browser, which works perfectly. The problem is that the extension must be clicked on to run; I am trying to get it to work so that it runs automatically without any user interaction necessary... is this possible?

Currently, my extension runs a HTML file when clicked on, which in turn calls a JS script coded to collect the email address. The code inserts this into the HTML and posts it to a PHP file. I have tried using `chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {});` within the js script but this does not work. Note: my JS script is not a service_worker, I do not know how I could get a service_worker script to run my other JS script.

If anyone can help, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome.runtime.onStartup never fires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621545/chrome-runtime-onstartup-never-fires)

Comment: That seems like a lot of faffing around. Is there any reason you can't just have one JS content script that loads when the page does, finds the email address, and then uses `fetch` to post it to the PHP endpoint?

Comment: @Andy The only thing is that I want it to run only once (when the browser loads)

Comment: Also @Andy, some of the APIs I am using does not work in content scripts

Comment: @KonradLinkowski unfortunately not, I had already looked at this. I can't find a way to trigger the code in my JS from the background script :(